# Prestashop - PayPal module doesn't appear after install

Tags: module, paypal, installation, prestashop

With the version 1.4.9  of Prestashop, I'm trying to install the PayPal module; downloaded from the official PS module repository, the installation ends successfully; but when I refresh the modules list it doesn't appear...

I've tried to install the module using the backend interface and also uploading the unzipped plugin to the /modules/ folder of the shop.

There are no errors shown and no disk space limitations.

Someone having/had same problem? I'm not new to PS and I've never had this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prestashop continued to alert me "**All the modules cannot be loaded due to memory limit restriction, please increase your memory limit value on your server configuration**"; searching on Prestashop Forum, I found this:
http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/185375-solucionado-instalar-paypal/
And doin' this

> Contacta con tu hosting, para que te aumenten el memory limit, puedes intentarlo tu, por ejemplo añadiendo esto:
>
> ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
>
> en el fichero /config/config.inc.php.

saved my day! In fact, Prestashop didn't load all modules and I didn't see PayPal after installation, while now is there :)